# Replacing Elements in a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I recently completed a program that will solve a simulated Rubik's cube, however, my solution's are always quite long as the program will often cycle through multiple rotations of a single layer to find a certain colour.

If you don't know what Rubik's cube notation is, basically a single letter represents a 90 degree clockwise rotation of the layer (U), a letter with an apostrophe is a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation (U'), and a letter followed by a 2 is a 180 rotation (U2).

What I'm trying to do is take any [U, U]s in my solution and turn them into [U2]s, and take any [U, U, U]s and make them [U']s. Essentially compress the solution down to a smaller size

I store my rotation letters as strings in a string vector, so what I'm thinking is making a loop like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    //and then check if there are similarities
    if (vector[i] == "U" && vector[i+1] == "U" && vector[i+2] == "U")
    {
        //Replace the first string with U' and delete the other 2 from the vector
    }
    else if (vector[i] == "U" && vector[i+1] == "U" && vector[i+2] != "U")
    {
        //Replace with U2
    }
    //Etc.
}
```

I'm just wondering if anyone has any more elegant solutions or if you can see flaws in mine (I have yet to implement it)

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when `i` is `vector.size() - 2` or `vector.size() - 1`? Oops.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by sticking to the [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to perform searching, and thus avoid having to worry about the boundary conditions.

I'd write a helper function that does the searching for you using [`std::search_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n) to find consecutive `U`s.

```
template<typename RanIter>
std::pair<RanIter, RanIter> do_search(RanIter first, RanIter last)
{
    // first look for 2 consecutive Us
    auto it = std::search_n(first, last, 2, "U");

    if(it == last) {
        // nothing to replace, bail
        return std::make_pair(last, last);
    }

    // check if we have 3 consecutive Us
    if(std::distance(it, last) >= 3) {
        // there are at least 3 elements in the range, it's ok to check
        if(*std::next(it, 2) == "U") {
            return std::make_pair(it, std::next(it, 3));
        }
    }

    return std::make_pair(it, std::next(it, 2));
}
```

The helper function returns a pair of iterators indicating the range of elements to be replaced. If the first element of the pair equals the `end()` of the vector there are no more elements to be replaced. Otherwise, depending on whether the distance between the pair elements is 2 or 3 we replace the range with `"U2"` or `"U'"` respectively.

```
while(first != vec.end()) {
    auto result = do_search(first, vec.end());
    first = result.first;
    if(first == vec.end()) {
        break;
    }

    auto dist = std::distance(first, result.second);
    if(dist == 3) {
        first = vec.insert(first, "U'");
    } else {
        first = vec.insert(first, "U2");
    }

    // advance first to the first element to be removed and erase them
    std::advance(first, 1);
    first = vec.erase(first, std::next(first, dist));
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ed0691eb0e97492)

Answer (score 0):

```
//as pointed out by chris if i = vector.size() - 2 you're in deep trouble
for (int i = 0; i < (vector.size()-2); i++)
{
    //and then check if there are similarities
    if (vector[i] == "U" && vector[i+1] == "U" && vector[i+2] == "U")
    {
        //Replace the first string with U' and delete the other 2 from the vector
    }
    else if (vector[i] == "U" && vector[i+1] == "U" && vector[i+2] != "U")
    {
        //Replace with U2
    }
    //Etc.
}
```

There fixed it.

Comment: This is still wrong since `i+2` will be out of bounds when `i == size-2`. PS. I didn't downvote.

Comment: agreed, i fixed it. forgot that vector indexing works just like array indexing

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    //and then check if there are similarities
    if (vector[i] == "U" )
    {
       if ( (i < vector.size() - 1) && (vector[i+1] == "U") )
       {
          if ( (i < vector.size() - 2) && (vector[i+2] == "U") )
          {
             // Replace the first string with U'
             // and delete the other 2 from the vector
          }
          else
          {
             //Replace with U2
          }
       }
       else
       {
          // Just a plain U
       }
    }

    else if {...}
    //Etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice pipja, chris, and Sahu. The way I actually ended up doing it was like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++)
    {
        if (solution[i] == solution[i+1] && solution[i+1] == solution[i+2]) //Check if there are 3 in a row
        {
            string temp = solution[i]; 
            //Check if it's legal to compress this (ie it isn't a triplet of [U']s
            bool isLegal = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
            {
                if (temp[i] == '\'' || temp[i] == '2')
                {
                    isLegal = false;
                }
            }
            if (isLegal == false)
            {
                continue;
            }
            temp+="'"; //Add an apostrophe
            //Replace and delete the others
            solution[i] = temp;
            solution.erase(solution.begin()+i+1);
            solution.erase(solution.begin()+i+2);

        }
        else if (solution[i] == solution[i+1] && solution[i+1] != solution[i+2]) //Repeat for if it's 2 in a row
        {
            string temp = solution[i];
            bool isLegal = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
            {
                if (temp[i] == '\'' || temp[i] == '2')
                {
                    isLegal = false;
                }
            }
            if (isLegal == false)
            {
                continue;
            }
            temp+="2";
            solution[i] = temp;
            solution.erase(solution.begin()+i+1);
        }
        else //This else solves the problem mentioned by Sahu
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

I'm fairly happy with it, it's not the most elegant solution but I think it's efficient

Comment: You still have out of bound accesses.